# Smartforms: form has wrong page format

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

SAP 730 Final Release Build 1429747 Patch Level 5

I am modifying a purchase order form; the form has a First and Next page; I added a Secondary window named 'Buyer' to both pages; before I add any elements, when I print preview the form I get the error

Form BUYER has wrong page format.
Message no. SSFCOMPOSER026

The Page Format in Form Attributes is LETTER; there is no different page format for this window.

I've read that this can be the result of some text areas containing too much text, however this window has no elements (yet).

Anyone run in to this issue before?  Many thanks.  I can post more info if needed.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this starting with an empty form or to provide a downloaded version of the form? Obviously none of us can debug a form on your system...

Comment: By "modifying". Do you mean you change an SAP standard form? If so, could you provide its name?

Comment: Not a standard SAP form - it is a customer form that was developed by someone else prior.  The form is fine until I add the new window for Buyer.  Not sure what it up - I may try copying an existing window and pasting as a new window to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Form TXT_CONTACT has wrong page format.
Message no. SSFCOMPOSER026

Diagnosis
Form TXT_CONTACT has a different page format than the forms output previously but has been added to the same spool request.

System Response
Form TXT_CONTACT ist not processed.

Procedure

While forms are formatted (FM SSFCOMP_OPEN to FM SSFCOMP_CLOSE), the page format must not be changed. All forms within one spool request must have the same page format.

The first page format used, in this case paper format , is applicable to all subsequent forms.